# Why is the pop function not running with stack[*top--] but working with with stack[*(top--)]?

Tags: c, function, switch-statement, stack, underflow

The problem is that I am unable to use the pop function.

```
int pop(int stack[],int *top,int item)
{
    if(*top==-1) {
        printf("Stack Underflow");
        return 0;
    }
    return stack[(*top)--]; 
}
```

Here, if I use `stack[*top--]` it doesn't seem to work! What is the difference? Why is the top variable in the main function is not getting decremented?

```c
int main()
{
    int stack[4], top = -1, item, id, ch;
    for(;;) {
        printf("Enter your choice:\n1.push\n2.pop\n3.Print top element\n4.Print all elements\n5.Exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        
        switch(ch) {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter the item to be pushed:\n");
            scanf("%d",&item);
            push(stack,&top,item);
            break;
        case 2:
            id=pop(stack,&top,item);
            printf("%d was popped\n",id);
            break;
        case 4:
            print(stack,&top,item);
            break;
        case 5:
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You just learned why it's a really bad idea to cram three operations into about 10 characters of code.  Your brain literally isn't able to handle the complexity of more than about 3 to 5 states at one time, and you just put three operations into 10 characters that's also on a line performing a return statement from a function.  If someone is teaching you to write code like that, I'd bet a considerable sum of money that they have never been on call, waiting to get called in from home in the wee hours of the night just to do an emergency fix for the bugs that such overly-complex code creates.

Comment: The other lesson here is about good encapsulation of data types.  These `push` and `pop` functions have lousily wide interfaces, requiring the caller to pass *both* the stack and the stack pointer, meaning that the stack pointer has to be passed by reference, so that the functions can modify it.  If instead there were a proper stack datatype, some kind of `struct stack`, and if pointers to that structure were passed around, things would have been simpler and clearer.  (But of course, at this stage in the class Chiranjit Debnath is taking, structures probably haven't been introduced yet.)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Lots of mediocre C instructors seem to be part of an almost mystically eternal chain, passing on to their hapless students the same misguided lessons they were taught by their own misguided instructors, who learned them from their misguided instructors before them.  None of these misguided instructors are qualified to do "real" programming, or to teach "real" programming to students; at best they can educate the next crop of misguided instructors, and the cycle continues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `(*top)--` does is:

1. Dereferences `top`, i.e. accesses the value which `top` is pointing to.
2. Decrements that value.

What `*top--` does is:

1. Decrements `top`, i.e. the value of `top` itself
2. Dereferences that value.

---

Besides that, I think it would be better if you define a stack structure instead of using a raw array and an integer as a pointer.

```c
#define STACK_CAPACITY 3 // Adjust it as you want

struct stack {
    int items[STACK_CAPACITY];
    int top;
};

void stack_init(struct stack *s)
{
    s->top = -1;
}

int stack_push(struct stack *s, int item)
{
    if (s->top == STACK_CAPACITY-1)
        return 0; // fail: stack is full

    s->items[++s->top] = item;
    return 1; // success: item pushed
}

int stack_pop(struct stack *s, int *top)
{
    if (s->top == -1)
        return 0;

    if (top != NULL) // if top is NULL, ignore it
        *top = s->items[s->top];

    s->top--;
    return 1;
}
```

Here is how you can use it:

```c
int main()
{
    struct stack s;
    stack_init(&s);

    if (!stack_push(&s, 1))
        printf("Stack is full\n");
    
    if (!stack_push(&s, 2))
        printf("Stack is full\n");
    
    if (!stack_push(&s, 3))
        printf("Stack is full\n");
    
    if (!stack_push(&s, 4))
        printf("Stack is full\n");
    
    if (!stack_push(&s, 5))
        printf("Stack is full\n");

    int item;
    stack_pop(&s, &item);
    printf("top = %d\n", item); // outputs 3

    stack_pop(&s, NULL); // Ignore the top

    stack_pop(&s, &item);
    printf("top = %d\n", item); // outputs 1
    
    if (!stack_pop(&s, NULL)) {
        printf("Stack is empty: cannot pop\n");
    }
}
```

---

Also, don't use `scanf()` to read user input. `fgets()` is much safer.

Answer (score 1):

In C, all postfix operators are higher precedence than all prefix (or infix) operators.  That's the way the langauge is defined.  So

```
*top--
```

is equivalent to

```
*(top--)
```

and if you want

```
(*top)--
```

you need the explicit parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

> `return stack[(*top)--];`
> `here if I use [*top--]`

`(*top)--` gets the object that `top` points to and decrements that object. Because `*top` points to the caller’s `top`, that is the value you want to use to look up an array element. Then `--` decrements the caller’s `top`, making it point to the next most recent item in the stack.

`*top--` is `*(top--)`, which decrements `top` and gets the object that the undecremented value points to. That also gets the caller’s `top`, but it decrements the function’s local `top`, not the caller’s object. Because the function’s `top` is decremented, it no longer points to the caller’s `top`.